# Inserting letters into a string at every possible spot

Tags: java, string

I am looking to insert a single letter one by one into every possible index of a string.

For example the string `ry`

Would go `"ary" "bry" "cry" ... "zry" ... "ray" "rby" .... "rzy" ... "rya" "ryb"`
I am not sure how to begin, any help?

Comment: did you try coding it on your own? Try to do it yourself, and if you run into problems, ask here for help. It's important to try and do it yourself first

Comment: @jroy8 Your example is inconsistent.  Everything except for the last two elements in your list shows a character being inserted _between_ two indices (or before the first index).  However, the last two elements in your list show a character _replacing_ the previous character at that index.

Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this 
`System.out.println("originaltext".replaceAll(".{1}","$0ry"));`

The above is using the String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) method - "Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement."

".{1}" - The regular expression used to find exactly one occurrence({1}) of any character(.)

"$0ry" - The replacement string with "$0" for the matched value followed by the required characters(ry).

This is repeated for all matches!

Comment: Try giving an explanation!

Comment: @GhostCat answer edited

Comment: This answer is correct.  However, it may not be answering the right question.  The example that @jroy8 provided mixes inserting characters into a string "between" two indices, and replacing characters in a string at an index.  It is unclear which operation the OP intended.

Answer (score 1):

## Example Code

```
String originalString = /* your original string */;
char[] characters = /* array of characters you want to insert */;
Vector<String> newStrings = new Vector<>();

String newString;
for (int idx = 0; idx < originalString.length() + 1; ++idx) {
    for (char ch : characters) {
        newString = originalString.substring(0, idx)
                  + ch
                  + originalString.substring(idx, originalString.length());
        newStrings.add(newString);
    }
}
```

---

---

## Explanation

### Processing all cases:

In order to insert every single letter into an index in a string, you need a loop to iterate through every letter.

In order to insert a letter into every index in a string, you need a loop to iterate through every index in the string.

To do both at once, you should nest one loop inside the other.  That way, every combination of an index and a character will be processed.  In the problem you presented, it does not matter which loop goes inside the other--it will work either way.

*(you actually have to iterate through every index in the string `+1`... I explain why below)*

### Forming the new string:

First, it is important to note the following:

- What you want to do is not "insert a character *into* an index" but rather "insert a character **between** two indices".  The distinction is important because you do not want to replace the previous character at that index, but rather move all characters starting at that index to the right by one index in order to make room for a new character "at that index."

This is why you must iterate through every index of the original string *plus one*.  Because once you "insert" the character, the length of the new string is actually equal to `originalString.length() + 1`, i.e. there are `n + 1` possible locations where you can "insert" the character.

Considering this, the way you actually form a new string (in the way you want to) is by getting everything to the left of your target index, getting everything to the right of your target index, and then concatenating them with the new character in between, e.g. `leftSubstring + newCharacter + rightSubstring`.

Now, it might seem that this would not work for the very first and very last index, because the leftSubstring and/or rightSubstring would be an empty string.  However, string concatenation still works even with an empty string.

---

---

### Notes about Example Code

- `characters` can also be any collection that implements `iterable`.  It does not have to be a primitive array.
- `characters` does not have to contain primitive `char` elements.  It may contain any type that can be concatenated with a String.
- Note that the `substring(int,int)` method of String returns the substring *including* the character at `beginIndex` *but not including* the character at `endIndex`.  One implication of this is that `endIndex` may be equal to `string.length()` without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will need a loop for from i = 0 to your string's length
Then another loop for every character you want to insert - so if you want to keep creating new strings with every possible letter from A to Z make a loop from char A = 'a' to 'z' and keep increasing them ++A(this should work in java).

This should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing, for instance, you want them all in a list, you could do something like that (iterating all places to insert and iterating over all letters):

```
List<String> insertLetters(String s) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++) {
        String prefix = s.substring(0, i);
        String postfix = s.substring(i, s.length());
        for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
            String newString = prefix + letter + postfix;
            list.add(newString);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String x = "ry";
    char[] alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    String[] alphabets2 = new String[alphabets.length];
    for (int i=0;i<alphabets.length;i++){
        char z = alphabets[i];
        alphabets2[i] = z + x;
    }
    for (String s: alphabets2
         ) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you would need a Array of alphabet (Easier for you to continue).

I will not give you exact answer, but something to start, so you would learn.

int length = 0;
     Arrays here

```
 while(length <= 2) {

     think what would be here: hint you put to index (length 0) the all alphabet and move to index 1 and then 2


 }
```

Comment: It is okay to not do his homework for him. But your answer doesn't contain **helpful** information. And the strange part about "array of alphabet" really does not make any sense.